# 2 Pin IR Receiver with Raspberry Pi

Tags: gpio

I am new with raspberry pi and I am trying to use a 2 pin IR Receiver and IR emitters to light an led when the IR emitter is turned on and when the emitter is off, turn the led off. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be efficient, the IR receiver with two pins (only a LED) needs to adjust your signal to a digital level. The tree pin IR receivers already have a demodulator which adjusts the output signal to adequate frequency and amplitude.

The IR emitter LED can be used directly with some circuit or only with a resistor, but with a modulator program it will be more efficient, like the `lirc` program.

Search for `lirc` in the internet.
I know that simpler is better, but sometimes it doesn't work better.
I wrote some ticks at http://martinho.comuf.com about `lirc` and Raspberry installs.